# Elastic search does not return proper result

Tags: elasticsearch

I have some tours as listed below.

- Memorable Istanbul
- Memorable Athens City Escape
- Memorable Rome City Escape
- Memorable Paris

I have created an index in elasticsearch as described below.

```
string newName = indexName + DateTime.Now.Ticks;
CreateIndexDescriptor createIndexDescriptor = new CreateIndexDescriptor(newName)
    .Settings(s => s
        .NumberOfShards(4)
        .NumberOfReplicas(2)
        .Setting("max_result_window", int.MaxValue)
        .Setting("max_ngram_diff", 25)
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(aa => aa
                .Custom("my_analyzer", ca => ca
                     .Tokenizer("standart")
                     .Filters("lowercase", "my_ascii_folding", "my_stemm", "stop")
                    )
                )
            .TokenFilters(t => t
                .AsciiFolding("my_ascii_folding", af => af.PreserveOriginal(true))
                .Stemmer("my_stemm", sm => sm.Language("english"))
                //.EdgeNGram("key_edgengram", ng => ng.MinGram(4).MaxGram(10))
            )
            .Tokenizers(t => t.Standard("standart"))
        )
    )
    .Map<T>(mm => mm.AutoMap().Properties(p => p.SearchAsYouType(t => t.Name(n => n.SearchingArea).Analyzer("my_analyzer"))));

MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
elasticClient.RequestResponseSerializer.Serialize(createIndexDescriptor, stream);
string jsonData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());

var indexResponse = elasticClient.Indices.Create(createIndexDescriptor);
```

when I try to search "memor" or "memorable" it returns all of them. but I trt to search "memorab" or "memorabl" it does not return any result.

Here is my search query:

```
GET /tourIndex/_search
{
  "from": 0,
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "searchingArea": {},
      "route": {}
    },
    "post_tags": [
      "</strong>"
    ],
    "pre_tags": [
      "<strong style='background: #efefef; padding: 3px;'>"
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "searchingArea": {
              "query": "memorab"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "size": 20,
  "sort": [
    {
      "score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The result was same when I use "match_phrase_prefix" and "match_phrase".

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a working example

**Index Mapping:**

```
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_tokenizer",
          "filter": "lowercase"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_tokenizer": {
          "type": "edge_ngram",
          "min_gram": 4,
          "max_gram": 15,
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "max_ngram_diff": 25
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "title": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "my_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Index Data:**

```
{
  "title": "Memorable Istanbul"
}
{
  "title": "Memorable Athens City Escape"
}
{
  "title": "Memorable Rome City Escape"
}
{
  "title": "Memorable Paris"
}
```

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "memorab"
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "66262920",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "4",
        "_score": 0.47070155,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Memorable Paris"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66262920",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.41747034,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Memorable Istanbul"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66262920",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.41747034,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Memorable Rome City Escape"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "66262920",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.38820273,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Memorable Athens City Escape"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will try it and let you know.

Comment: @ypbr did you get a chance to go through the answer, looking forward to get feedback from you :)